# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database master

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-express

first off

> I know that this question is a duplicate!

But the problem feels weird, maybe someone knows how to deal with it.

I added a new user to my SQL Server:

- SQL Authentification
- Server role public, dbcreator and sysadmin
- Ticked every checkbox in "Securables" (Modify any database, create any db, ...)

And still get the error message "permission denied in database master". Do I have to grant any other permissions? I even manually granted permissions:

```
USE [master]
GO
GRANT CREATE ANY DATABASE TO [Hans]
```

Still no success. What else could I be doing wrong? I am just trying to add a new database, create some tables, ... nothing special about that.

Comment: I would assume that just being SYSADMIN should be enough for your user to do whatever. No need to tick all the securables boxes.

Comment: The user is sysadmin, it doesn't work :/

Comment: You are sure you are connected with said user? Do other sysadmin users face the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I am connected with the new user. Cannot check at the moment if other sysadmins face the same issues, sorry ..
Addition: I am connecting to a remote server, but this shouldn't make any difference.. (?)

Comment: GRANT CREATE ANY  DATABASE does not allow connections to any database.  That allows the user to create a new database, for which by default they will have db_owner.

Your users should not have sysadmin unless they are the DBA.

Can you post the full text of the error message when the try to connect?  Where are they connecting from? SSMS?